# DocFX - Unable to filter out public Method from API Documentation

Tags: c#, docfx

I have the following method in my class library that I want to hide from API documentation:

```cs
namespace com.contoso.myns
{
    public class myclass
    {
        public static string CreateSomething()
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the [DocFX Tutorial for filtering API documentation](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/howto_filter_out_unwanted_apis_attributes.html#2-attribute-filter-rules) to create **filterConfig.yml**. In that file I have the following:

```
- exclude:
    uidRegex: '^com\.contoso\.myns\.myclass\.Create[^.]+$'
    type: Method
```

However, the method is still appearing in my documentation.

Please note:

- I have other filters defined in **filterConfig.yml** which *are* working as-expected, so the file is being picked up and properly parsed by DocFX.
- I tested the regex pattern (^com.contoso.myns.myclass.Create[^.]+$) using [this regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) and it does match the fully-qualified name of the method I want to exclude.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to match a method name shouldn't contain the entire path from the namespace; just the method name itself:

```
- exclude:
    uidRegex: 'CreateSomething$'
    type: Method
```

Comment: Wouldn't this exclude every method called `CreateSomething`, regardless of which class it is declared on?

Comment: @Amy Yep. But again, when I fully-qualified the Method starting from the namespace, DocFX wouldn't recognize it as a match even though it clearly does match from a regex perspective.

This is probably something I should bring up on the GitHub project page.